# Why can I run svn inside Docker?

Tags: java, linux, docker, gradle, svn

I have something that works that I think should not work:
Im attempting to checkout java code and run a build inside a Docker container

```
FROM openjdk:8
COPY . /usr/src/myapp
WORKDIR /usr/src/myapp
CMD ["./checkoutAndRunGradle.sh"]
```

where "checkoutAndRunGradle.sh" is following content:

```
#!/bin/sh
svn checkout svn://mysvnserver/myrepo/trunk
cd trunk
sh gradlew clean build
```

The thing is that this works perfectly, which is strange because I didnt add svn to the Dockerfile! Svn is indeed available in my host environment, so does it reach the host in some way, or is it included in openjdk?

Answer (score 5):

The OpenJDK 8 Docker image extends from buildpack-deps:stretch-scm, which installs Subversion:

https://github.com/docker-library/buildpack-deps/blob/1845b3f918f69b4c97912b0d4d68a5658458e84f/stretch/scm/Dockerfile